# Best way to include Google-Java-Client API with Google Contacts in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-api-java-client

How to include the Google Java Client API in Android Studio...possibly via gradle? Also, I want to manage Google Contacts...so which other library can I include and how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for setting up the Google Java client APIs is at https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup. Looking at their Maven coordinates for the Android client libraries, the relevant coordinate string is `com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc`. You can go to **Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + > Library dependency** and add it there.

For managing Google Contacts, start with the `ContactsContract` API and follow the docs from there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html