# Apache HttpClient Android (Gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apache-httpcomponents, multipartentity

I have added this line to my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
```

and I want to use MultipartEntityBuilder in my code. However Android studio doesn't add the library to my code.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is that line in the top-level `dependencies` closure? Do you have `mavenCentral()` configured in the top-level `repositories` closure?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm new to this can you explain more please? what do you mean by top-level closure? and how can i check whether mavencentral is configured there

Comment: Given the errors you are reporting in your comments on the one answer below, you already have these parts set up.

Comment: @CommonsWare why not `jcenter()`? It has more artifacts, better search, copy-paste snippets for Gradle and that's what Android Studio recommends.

Comment: @CommonsWare Everything you find on Maven Central is in JCenter as well, so you are safe with that. But both Gradle and Android Studio are much more `jcenter()` than Maven Central. 
There is also an outstanding issue to switch Gradle, Please to look in jcenter.

Comment: Refer to this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782727/gradle-build-failed-apache-httpentity/32344127#32344127

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you are using target SDK as 23 add the below code in your build.gradle

```
android{
 useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

**Additional note here:** don't try using the gradle versions of those files. They are broken (28.08.15). I tried over 5 hours to get it to work. It just doesn't.
**not working:**

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

**Another thing** **don't** use:

```
'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

**It's referring to 21 API level.**

Comment: It's not just target SDK, also happens if you use compile SDK 23, and proguard will still throw errors on that as well

Comment: After adding these three jars and already my project has google play service, fbook sdk, appcompat_v7 so I got and error of 65K method, can you please suggest proguard for above libs?

Comment: @Chitrang you can also make your app multidex ;):)

Comment: @Chitrang use android{ useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy' } add this to your build.gradle file remove above compilefile dependencies

Comment: @JINUJAYAKUMAR i'm getting useLibrary cannot resolved to a type and error Gradle DSL method not found 'useLibrary()'

Comment: did your target sdk is 23 and build tools is 23.0.0  use this link for more info http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: @chiru update your gradle.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade

Comment: do not use multidex if possible, it multiplied compile time from 15seconds to 2minutes

Comment: Simply adding "android{ useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy' }" resolved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer does not seem quite right to me. There is no point dragging a different version of HttpMime when one can depend on the same version of it.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
}
```

Comment: I ended up downloading the jar files since I couldnt get the correct version from gradle

Comment: And that's what i told you and you unaccepted my answer

Comment: Using API level 23 this does not work very well. Actually the answer below from Jinu worked for me. Adding `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` in android section solved my case.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this to your dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-alpha1'
```

And generally if you want to use a library and you are searching for the Gradle dependency line you can use [Gradle Please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)

EDIT: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076102/best-way-to-include-google-java-client-api-with-google-contacts-in-android-studi) one too.

Comment: I get this error: Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-alpha1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Comment: Then there is no reason adding it if it's already included in the Android System!

Comment: but i cannot import the library

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbol 'MultipartEntityBuilder' and it doesn't recommend any import.

Comment: @HiradRoshandel: Hopefully there are more instructions somewhere, from the maintainers of the `httpclient-android` artifact, explaining how to properly use that artifact in an Android Studio/Gradle for Android project.

Comment: @Pavlos is there any way not to get the alpha version? and get previous versions

Comment: You will have to search for previous jar versions i guess

Answer (score 8):

None of the others worked for me. I had to add the following dependency, as explained [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html)

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
```

because I was targeting API 23.

Comment: That's really the best option, sad to see it so low. I described why it is better the legacy jar and whatever here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37623038/1727132

Comment: same case here, I had to do the same

Answer (score 4):

I resolved problem by adding following to my build.gradle file

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
```

However this only works if you are using gradle 1.3.0-beta2 or greater, so you will have to add this to buildscript dependencies if you are on a lower version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2'
```

Comment: `Could not find method android() for arguments`.

Answer (score 2):

I searched over and over this solution works like a charm ::

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.anzma.memories"
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
 packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: For future reference please separate the textual part of the answers from the code, to improve readability and quality of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but (for now) [httpclient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1) can be compiled **only** as a jar into the libs directory in your project.
[HttpCore](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3) works fine when it is included from mvn like that:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working gradle dependency

Try this:

> compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'