# Gradle build failed - Apache HttpEntity

Tags: android, apache, httpclient

I get this error when I try to run my application:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/.../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/NOTICE
    Origin 1: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5/82edcaec6c7b4599eaeaaf11167ceea41db42f33/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar
    Origin 2: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.5/1dd0d38df9c6d21e893f2e52403f1cd99e91cd81/httpmime-4.3.5.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
    File 1: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5/82edcaec6c7b4599eaeaaf11167ceea41db42f33/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar
    File 2: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5/82edcaec6c7b4599eaeaaf11167ceea41db42f33/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.754 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    }

}
```

I simply want to import the following libraries:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

so I can run the following code:

```
       String sendProfileData = getResources().getString(R.string.URL);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(sendProfileData);

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        try {
            mpEntity.addPart("first_name", new StringBody("Jay"));
            mpEntity.addPart("last_name", new StringBody("Shmidt"));
            ...
        }
        ...
```

What exactly is wrong here - Do I actually need to delete or replace jar files? Why isn't gradle taking care of this?

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I got the answer from this post

[Android Gradle plugin 0.7.0: "duplicate files during packaging of APK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk)

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not problem in Android Studio only your system require internet connection

1. Just extends class MultipartEntity
2. Than press Alt+Enter
3. Than click find jar on web
4. Select httpmime-4.0-alpha4.jar
5. Than right click on project structure
6. Click open module setting
7. In dependencies tab click on + icon on right side
8. Than click on file dependency select http:mime file added
9. Finally build project