# org.apache.http.legacy not being imported into project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-mnc

I have an app with two modules.
One module acts as a library and uses the Apache HTTP. Now I must compile it with MNC-Preview but, as known, this framework is no longer part of SDK framework.
Being that the case, I read that it is possible to import `org.apache.http.legacy`as a lib to make it work.

So, basically I have this in my module gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    (...)
}
```

And in the main gradle I have

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade) but still getting the error that the apache package does not exist.

**UPDATE:** Seems that the code compiles, my bad. However the code in the IDE is marked as not found, I get a lot of errors and no auto complete. Did anyone went thru this?

Comment: I have the same issue, and reported about it : http://stackoverflow.com/q/31653002/878126 . Did you find a solution for it?