# Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,DefaultHttpClient in Android Studio

Tags: android, httpclient

Hi I am new for android in my app I am integrating with services so when I  import all these jar files. It gives an error :

> Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,DefaultHttpClient.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

### my build gradle:-

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HttpClient was deprecated in API Level 22** and **removed** in API Level 23. You have to use `URLConnection`.

If you anyway need in 23, add this to your gradle::

```
android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

NOTE: Instead, I would recommend using [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: @Krish have a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607257/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-httpresponce-in-android-studio

Comment: that's what i did in my build gradle file

Comment: can you post full `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` was deprecated in `API Level 22` and removed in `API Level 23`

So if your target `API Level 23` or `>=23` then you need to use

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in `build.gradle` file.

Also this is the good library http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ which support `API level 23` and also `>=23`

Answer (score 0):

Apache Http is deprecated. Add

`useLibrary org.apache.http.legacy`

in app's build.gradle file in defaultConfig to use apache httpclient.

Answer (score 0):

At first read this **[Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,HttpResponce in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607257/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-httpresponce-in-android-studio)**

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To
>   continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the
>   following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" // Set Yours
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // You should add this 
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html