# Why I can't use HttpClient in AS

Tags: android, httpclient

Why I can't use `HttpClient` in Android Studio? my ADT:23, My SDK:24. Isn't it good to use `HttpClient` to replace `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354402/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-defaulthttpclient-in-android-studio/36354461#36354461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Android 6.0 release removed support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the `HttpURLConnection` class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) for more info.