# Using org.appache.http.client in android studio

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I'm using `org.apache.http.client` in the app I recently moved from Eclipse to Android Studio and I meet a new problem. Despite the fact that I have added a dependency to `org.apache.httpComponents.httpCore_4.4.4.jar`, which caused errors in the editor to disappear, when building the project, I get the following error message : "error : package org.apache.http.client does not exist".

Where am I wrong and what should I do to correct the problem?

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653002/how-to-use-the-legacy-apache-http-client-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354402/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-defaulthttpclient-in-android-studio/36354461#36354461

Comment: android{
 useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
} use this in gradle file

Comment: it is deprecated. try using okhttp instead

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676049/the-import-org-apache-http-client-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-i-update-sdk-to/35211175#35211175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android 6.0` release removes support for the Apache HTTP client you can use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead

or you can add

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in your build.gradle for target sdk 23

```
android{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

see this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)