# The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved error when I update sdk to M

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am getting following errors when I import project into eclipse. I have updated my sdk to M.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
```

Comment: add latest gradle from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For eclipse -- Find library in your sdk and add it manually
`platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar`

For android studio add this line in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: awesome one liner but time saver.

Answer (score 9):

for android studio add one line in build.gradle file of app like:

```
android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       ....
       defaultConfig {
       ..
       ..
       }
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**apache http** and `NameValuePair` has been deprecated in api 23. youl have to manualy add apache library [check this](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) .

or may be you should start using from now `HttpURLConnection` . check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561084/3479012) for same

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same is,

Find `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` which is in `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional,` add it to your dependency.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32328502/3036759)