# "HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionParams" Does not work in my android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-import

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionParams

Why this function does not work in my android studio.

Source Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VJE8.png

Comment: [HttpConnectionParams](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes/org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.html) is now deprecated

Comment: This is a _Question_ & Answer site, so when posting a question, don't just post a statement. Also, _"does not work"_ could mean just about anything (does the code fail to compile? does it crash? did your computer explode?). You need to be a lot more specific when explaining a problem to other people.

Comment: Please post your code @Abdullah al Hasan

Comment: You can use **HTTPURLConnection** instead

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676049/the-import-org-apache-http-client-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-i-update-sdk-to/35211175#35211175

Comment: It does work in Android Studio. The strike through line indicates that the HttpConnectionParams is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @Adnan What should I use then?