# Unable to find HTTP client library - Android

Tags: android, httpclient

I have multiple modules in my project and have added the following dependency in my project level `build.gradle` file for using HTTP Client Library throughout the project:

```
 compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"
```

I created a new module and I want to use the above mentioned library in it. So here is what I did in `build.gradle` for that module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    useLibrary 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

I have been following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc). Upon trying to sync the project I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to find optional library: cz.msebera.android.httpclient

I can't figure out what went wrong here. Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676049/the-import-org-apache-http-client-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-i-update-sdk-to/35211175#35211175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved error when I update sdk to M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676049/the-import-org-apache-http-client-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-i-update-sdk-to)

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency in your build.gradle(Module: app):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: I added to module gradle and it is work.according this site :https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html  version: '4.3.5.1' is for Android API 22 and older  but  version: '4.4.1.1' is for Android API 23 and newer . thnx.

Answer (score 1):

use this
   `compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'`  or you can use library directly from [HERE](http://central.maven.org/maven2/cz/msebera/android/httpclient/4.4.1.1/httpclient-4.4.1.1.jar) and paste it in your lib folder and choose *add as library* by right click on that library after paste.

Comment: i used like this: compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.2'

Comment: than only thing you have to do is download this library and put in your lib folder

Comment: I do but still DefaultHttpClient is deprecated.

Comment: replace *HttpClient* place of DefaultHttpClient

Comment: HttpClient  does not have getCookieStore(). this is my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420640/client-getcookiestore-getcookies-on-httpurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Comment: instead of `cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.21 on build.gredle of the main ?or module?

Comment: @sayreskabir you would need to write in in module dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Update answer for Android IDE dolphin 2021 on 12/2022
-Using cz.msebera.android , remove all org.apache.httpcomponents . Apache library create conflict with android sdk >=30.  Adding this line to build.gradle file:
implementation 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.5.8'

-Modify all import from org.apche.http to cz.msebera.

-You can reference to my project at:  https://github.com/tamobi1991/RssFeeda