# Legacy Apache HttpClient with multidex

Tags: android, apache

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade), when targeting Android M we can use the following to build our project: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

This helps to build debug version of our app. However when trying to build the release version with Proguard we get the following error from gradle:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shrinkXXX5ReleaseMultiDexComponents'.> java.io.IOException: The output jar [/Users/.../projects/XXX/build/intermediates/multi-dex/XXX/release/componentClasses.jar] must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty.
```

Clearly there is some issue with legacy http client and multidex. Anyone has a solution for this?

We use `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` and `multiDexEnabled true` for our release build

Comment: your error should be the final result only, try to find the line mentioning the cause above and post here