# app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am searching for three days now, but I don't find a answer of these Exception:

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my build.gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }



}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
}
```

When I sync, clean and build the gradle project everythink is fine, but when I want to run the App I got this Exception...
Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you checked method count for libraries you have in 'libs' folder? could it be `multidex` issue?

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes, but my Problem is that i need the org.apache.http.legacy API for the connection between the app and my mySQL DB on my own Server. Do you have a solution for this connection without the Apache HTTP Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the following:

- Android's internal Apache library
- Multidex
- Jars

Try this new config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar') // I would use MP Android Chart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to see in your dependencies `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` and also `minifyEnabled false`.

Pleae check if you exceed amount of 65K methods for your code & libraries you are using so you'll need to use multidexing, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception). You can also follow [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) recommendations to implement multidexing properly.

Also here are known issues with `'org.apache.http.legacy'` if you are using some old gradle build tools version, see [How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade for Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo)