# Android Studio deprecated on HttpParams, HttpConnectionParams, ConnManagerParams, setTimeout

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm new in Android programming. I want to make app that can connect Android to the web server. Here's the code that I use:

```
public void cari (View v){

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> arData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        arData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", edNama.getText().toString()));
        String respon = null;

        try {
            respon = KoneksiHTTP.eksekusiHttpPost("http://example.com/myphp.php", arData);
            String r = respon.toString();
            r = r.trim();

            AlertDialog close = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("ESTIMASI MANFAAT")
                    .setMessage(r.toString())
                    .setNegativeButton("Kembali", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            edNama.setText(null);
        }
}
```

and this another class

```
public class KoneksiHTTP {

    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 3000;
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (client == null) {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams parameterHttp = client.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameterHttp, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(parameterHttp, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return client;
    }

    public static String eksekusiHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameter) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            HttpClient klien = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost req = new HttpPost(url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    postParameter);
            req.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse resp = klien.execute(req);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
            StringBuffer stringBuff = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuff.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String hasil = stringBuff.toString();
            return hasil;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got **deprecated** on

> HttpParams, HttpConnectionParams, ConnManagerParams, setTimeout.

I've been adding

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

but it has no effect. What should I used instead ?

here's my build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.plz.taspenmobile"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

code for showing respon:

```
try {
            CallWebService respon = new CallWebService("POST", "http://example.com/myphp.php", apiParams) {
                @Override
                public void OnStartingService() {
                    super.OnStartingService();
                }

               //@Override
                public void OnGettingResult(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException, MethodNotDefinedException {
                    super.OnGettingResult(toString());
                }
            };


            String r = respon.toString();
            r = r.trim();
            AlertDialog close = new AlertDialog.Builder(estimasi.this)
                    .setTitle("Estimasi Manfaat")
                    .setMessage(r.toString())
                    .setNegativeButton("Kembali", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    })
                    .show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            edNama.setText(null);
        }
```

Comment: you have to use `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the warning without changing your code, or are you looking for an alternative way to use Apache HTTPClient?

Comment: @DougStevenson     
 
is it possible to remove the warning without changing my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade for Android M?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo)

Comment: @DougStevenson I've try to add that, but doesn't affected

Comment: Show your build.gradle.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've update my question with my build gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i think you should switch over to httpURlConnection. just visit [this](http://aiyazparmar.blogspot.in/2016/02/call-web-service-andorid-wihout-using.html)
link here i have added global class for calling webservice and getting response in json.

replace this code in your CallWebService file you will get response in string.

```
public class CallWebService {

    private static final String GET="GET";
    private static final String POST="POST";
    private HashMap<String,String> apiParameters;
    private static String WebService;

    public CallWebService(String MethodType, String WebService, HashMap<String, String> apiParameters) throws MethodNotDefinedException {
            if(MethodType!=null) {
                if (MethodType.equalsIgnoreCase(GET)) {
                    if(WebService!=null){
                        this.WebService=WebService;
                        new ExecuteAsyncTask(GET).execute();
                    }else{
                       throw new NullPointerException("Please define webservice url.");
                    }
                } else if(MethodType.equalsIgnoreCase(POST)){
                    if(WebService!=null){
                        if(apiParameters!=null)this.apiParameters=apiParameters;
                        this.WebService=WebService;
                        new ExecuteAsyncTask(POST).execute(apiParameters);
                    }else{
                        throw new NullPointerException("Please define webservice url.");
                    }
                }else{
                    throw new MethodNotDefinedException("Define method for webservice.");
                }
            }else{
                throw new MethodNotDefinedException("Define method for webservice.");
            }
    }

    private class ExecuteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String,String>,Void,String>{
        String MethodType;
        public ExecuteAsyncTask(String MethodType){
            this.MethodType=MethodType;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            OnStartingService();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            super.onPostExecute(string);
            try {
                OnGettingResult(string);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MethodNotDefinedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(HashMap<String, String>... params) {
            if(MethodType.equalsIgnoreCase(GET))
            return getJSON(WebService,15000);
            else try {
                return getJSONPOST(WebService,params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void OnStartingService(){
    }
    public void OnGettingResult(String jsonObject) throws JSONException, MethodNotDefinedException {
    }





    private String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }  finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    private String getJSONPOST(String url1, HashMap<String,String> apiParams) throws IOException, JSONException {
        URL url = new URL(url1);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String getParams=getQuery(apiParams);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getParams);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                return sb.toString();
        }


        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }




    private String getQuery(HashMap<String,String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;


        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: create file CallWebservice and paste that code in that and after that i have mentioned how to call api in last .

Comment: you will get response in OnGettingResult(JSONObject jsonObject) this function when you override it just search that function in that link . that function specified in the last. just check that out and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: My web service respon is not a JSONObject, how do I use this?

org.json.JSONException: Value Mohon of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i updated my answer just replace that code with this new code.

Comment: thanks sir, it help me a alot. But the respon on my web service doesn't show on my Android device, it just show on my logcat like this "02-24 14:25:25.802 19556-20018/com.example.plz.taspenmobile I/System.out: "My Web Service Response"

Comment: and on my Android device show "com.example.plz.taspenmobile.estimasi$1@fb46db8"

Comment: I have updated my question, adding the code for response

Comment: public void OnGettingResult(String response) throws JSONException, MethodNotDefinedException { super.OnGettingResult(response);  System.out.println(response);} put your response code inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HttpURLConnection`.

Use below 2 methods for reference.

**1. For GET method.**

```
public static String getHttpResponse(String url) {

        StringBuffer responseString = null;
        String inputLine;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            URL dataUrl = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) dataUrl.openConnection();
            // optional default is GET
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                responseString = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseString.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Some error occured", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //If you want further info on failure...
                return null;
            }
        }
        return responseString.toString();
    }
```

**2. For POST method.**

```
    public static String postHttpResponse(String dataUrl, HashMap<String, String> postData) {

        StringBuffer responseString = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String inputLine;

        try {
            URL postUrl = new URL(dataUrl);
            String email_id = postData.get("email_id");
            String device_id = postData.get("device_id");
            String status = postData.get("status");

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) postUrl.openConnection();

            String urlParameters = "device_id=" + device_id + "&email_id=" + email_id + "&status=" + status;
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                responseString = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseString.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //If you want further info on failure...
                return null;
            }
        }
        return responseString.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional advice from me is using `Android Volley`. You can see information and usage here : [Training With Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: You can import volley on there : https://bintray.com/android/android-utils/com.android.volley.volley/view
and follow guides on above site.

Answer (score 0):

Place this @SuppressWarnings annotation on your class definition that uses HttpClient:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class YourClassThatUsesHttpClient {
    ...
}
```

But your app could still break in a future version of Android, so migrate your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks sir, but it still have no effect. It just make the warning dissapear

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what you asked for, when you said "is it possible to remove the warning without changing my code".

Answer (score 0):

```
String r = apiParams.toString();
                    r = r.trim();
                    AlertDialog close = new AlertDialog.Builder(estimasi.this)
                            .setTitle("Estimasi Manfaat")
                            .setMessage(r.toString())
                            .setNegativeButton("Kembali", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
```