# Android Studio not able to find org.apache.http.legacy after SDk update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk, build.gradle

I updated my SDK  and Android studio is not able to recognise `'org.apache.http.legacy'`library.

There is not `org.apache.http.legacy.jar update` which should be `in /platforms/android-23/optional path` after update.

I am not able to gradle sync my project.

**Note:** I am using android useLibrary `'org.apache.http.legacy'` in my build.gradle

Comment: Try [This answer it may be work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this under `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` line in your build.gradle like this:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bui but this doesn't work. Same error persist.