# Android Logcat Message "Could not find Class"

Tags: android

i have downgraded the compile SDK from API 23 to API 22 now after downgrade i am receiving the following messages in logcat.

need you kind assistance to reduce errors.
i have updated this question with gradle app file as well

```
    04-16 20:36:35.814 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.814 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.814 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.814 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.824 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.824 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.824 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.824 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:35.844 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.SplashScreen.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.907 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.917 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.917 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.917 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.917 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.927 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.927 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.937 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:38.947 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.MainActivity.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.376 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.386 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:36:58.396 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.ShowTasbeedandAddTasbeen.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.069 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.069 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.079 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.079 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.079 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.079 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.079 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.089 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:02.089 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.arsal.androtasbih.TasbeehCounter.access$super
04-16 20:37:28.415 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-16 20:37:29.726 27855-27855/com.example.arsal.androtasbih E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Gradle File is as below. i have changed compile sdk to 22 and also changed built tool number and also performed changes in dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arsal.androtasbih"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile files('C:/Users/Arsal/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroTasbih/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your app gradle file also

Comment: What is the reason for downgrading? If there is another problem, we may fix it.

Comment: @oguzhand i am using web services in this application and HTTPClient is obsolete in api 23 and i need to use it.

Comment: You can leave the compile SDK version at 23 and still run the code on API 22

Comment: If you need the Apache libraries for HTTP, please see.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo

Comment: @cricket_007 if i leave the compile sdk to 23, would it be supporting httpclient?

Comment: See the link I just posted

Answer (score 1):

Anytime I change libraries or build levels, especially going down in versions, I always invalidate caches and restart. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpclient in version 23.Just add this in your app build.gradle file.

```
    android {
           compileSdkVersion 23
           buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
           useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
           -------------------
           --------------------   }
```