# POST-ing JSON request to FCM server isn't working

Tags: android, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-json

I am trying to send request to Firebase server for FCM and as FCM documentation says it should be POST request with JSON data. This is the sample.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

So can anyone give the a proper code that will send POST request with this JSON data?

This is what I tried but it is not working

**AsyncT.java**

```
package com.example.artin.pushnotifications;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"); //Enter URL here
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key=AIzaSyDZx9l_Izta9AjVS0CX70ou8OjbDVVGlHo");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
            param.put("Hii","there");

            jsonObject.put("data",param);
            jsonObject.put("to", "dXazhmeFSSU:APA91bG23o75zeNOCb7pY-OCQG4BsGbY-YZrSnDrvLWv1");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

And I execute it when button is pressed

```
AsyncT asyncT = new AsyncT();
asyncT.execute();
```

Comment: So many duplicates and you haven't provided what you tried already.

Comment: `Volley` is good, but `OkHttp` is nice too. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36160967/2308683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending POST data in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

Comment: @cricket_007 non of them is working but ill edit it right now

Comment: Ok, and is there an exception, or Firebase isn't doing anything?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't see any exceptions. Firebase isn't doing anything and also i get from the logcat (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like PostMan to verify that your POST contents are correct? That's usually the first thing I do when testing REST API services

Comment: Yes I tried and it works perfectly.

Comment: It works from postman but not from the code

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then. I want to say that `key=` isn't part of the property. But not completely sure

Comment: cricket_007 OkHttp finally worked out. Thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used OkHttp and now it works. Here is the code if someone need it.

First add OkHttp into apps graddle.build

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Here is the method for sending POST Json request

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Call post(String url, String json, Callback callback) {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization","key=YourApiKey")
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
        return call;
    }
```

And just create Json object and call it where you want.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    param.put("Hii", "there");
    param.put("Hours", "12:50");
    jsonObject.put("data", param);
    jsonObject.put("to", "TokenOfTheDevice");
    post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", jsonObject.toString(), new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    //Something went wrong
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String responseStr = response.body().string();
                        Log.d("Response", responseStr);
                        // Do what you want to do with the response.
                    } else {
                        // Request not successful
                    }
                }
            }
    );
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Log.d("Exception", "JSON exception", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using AsyncTask, HTTPRequest

```
    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

      String Url = "//fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);

        try {
          //add data
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data[0]));
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          //execute http post
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
      }
    }
```

This can be called using
`new PostTask().execute();`

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated from android

Comment: @Aram Sheroyan yes, `HttpClient` is deprecated but you can use it. Just add compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2' to your `build.gradle` dependencies.

Comment: @Stanojkovic That isn't [completely correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32741791/2308683)

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right, but even without useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' it still works and Android Studio doesn't give the message "cannot resolve symbol..."