# Waiting for user permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio

The Below is code for asking user permissions.If the user gives permissions then i have to take him to the next screen.After user allows permissions..then i have to take him to next screen

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
            }
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

If I use the code below.

`onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`

it is showing this error

> "the method is not overriding anything with current build target,but will in api 23 current level 17"

Comment: Change Your target SDK version to 23.

Comment: @Janak.....Target SDK is 23 only .....

Comment: No, also set compileSdkVersion to 23 and change build version according to compile SDK Version.

Comment: What you have Extend with MainActivity?

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) this method override only with FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity

Comment: @anonymous... it is also work with Activity class.

Comment: ok............. @Janak

Comment: @Janak......But It will affect previous versions.....This is very old application..I am using HTTP Client for this.If I change compilesdkversion to 23....The Old things are not recognised

Comment: @Teja... Write --> useLibrary('org.apache.http.legacy') in your Gradel above defaultConfig to use old HTTP Client.

Comment: Do i need to add that dependency.....It is showing..unable to find the library

Comment: @Teja.. check :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo

Comment: @Teja... android official doc : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: @Janak..IDK......I have tried all the solutions that i have got...It is showing the same error