# Using Apache HTTP APIs in Android Application

Tags: android, apache, http, legacy

For those who still needed to use `org.apache.http.legacy` in their Android application, as of **compiled SDKVersion 26**.

You have to do two things:

> 1. Include android `{useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}` in your `build.gradle(Module)`
> 2. Under `dependencies {}`, include `compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'`

Comment: Is it a question?

Comment: new account, no reputation so cannot give a comment, just posting so it might help someone who facing the same problem

Comment: Post an answer to existing question if any, or create your own question, than post an answer to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade for Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo)