# HttpClient is not imprting in Android studio

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I gone through all the post and Add the line,

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in app build.gradle and changed the

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
 }
```

***But still it is not importing! can any one suggest me what i'm missing here?***

Comment: add jar files for HttpClient

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024908/apache-httpclient-android-gradle

Comment: Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I already checked them and did what they said. not helping!

Comment: I recommend using volley.Volley is the simple and easy to use compared to httpclient. Just a suggestion

Comment: @sandeep thanks for the suggestion! can you tell me why HttpResponce is not working after importing the jar file

Comment: First thing is..Httpclient is deprecated. It would be cumbersome if you use httclient with jar. But for now if its saying httpresponse cannot resolve, obviously jar not added correctly.

Comment: So try this way.. copy the jar and add it in the library folder and right click on the jar and add as library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download jar file [HttpClient.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient423jar.htm).Then add into lib folder on your project.Then fix the path on settings

```
 File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add -> File Dependency
```

Android Studio opens a dialog box where you can drag&drop the jar library. Then  click the OK button.

Comment: sasikumar, can you elaborate the process as I was beginer I may miss some thing!

Comment: I jsut downloaded the .jar file

Comment: paste into your project libs folder ..then goto File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add -> File Dependency and select that jar..click ok

Comment: extract zipfile ... .jar format need,,but you select zip file that why this problem.

Comment: how to get HttpResponce?