# can't use HttpPost in Android Studio after successful Gradle sync

Tags: android, gradle, http-post

I'm trying to use HttpPost as I did in the past in Android. I realize that it has been removed from recent Android versions. Following the solutions on a similar StackOverflow question, I added this to my Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

After a Gradle sync that complained of no errors, I still cannot import the HttpPost program. In fact, the org.apache.http.client.methods package does not resolve at all.

I also tried what the Apache HttpClient website suggested, which was to use this instead in my Gradle dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Once again, the sync went fine, and this time the package resolved, but not the HttpPost program.

[image]

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433687/android-gradle-apache-httpclient-does-not-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this line in your `build.gradle` inside android plugin :

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Comment: But these are old versions of the Apache clients, yes? Wouldn't it be better to have the newer versions? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The answer above is quite full and describes the whole problem, in API 23 this client was fully removed and became just a legacy. I think it's better to use HttpOk, Retrofit or simply UrlConnection.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache HttpClient 4.3 for Android meant to be an update for the legacy 4.0 alpha version that was included in early Android versions. To avoid naming conflicts some on the updated classes got the postfix `HC4`, like `HttpPostHC4` for example, which one had to use instead.

But now that the old HttpClient was removed form Android, the old classes like `HttpPost` do not exist anymore.

The official way to get the HttpClient library on newer Android version is to use:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

as [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065636/559745).