# Android: gradle DSL methdod not found

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am importing an existing android project into the android studio.
But i will get the following error.

> INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Gradle DSL method not found:
>   'useLibrary()'
>   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with
>   Gradle for project 'android' failed: Gradle DSL method not found:
>   'useLibrary()'

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

ext {
    apply from: 'cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    publishNonDefault true
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024908/apache-httpclient-android-gradle