# Missing org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest on Android app

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm trying to use Telegrambot from my Android application (4.4 due to some project requirements). I implemented a simple bot but, when I tried to run it, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest

    at com.mypackage.Model.communication.remote.telegram.TelegramBotTest.initialize(TelegramBotTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I have tried with

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3'
```

but without success. What's the proper dependency I have to include? These are the dependencies I have included to support telegram:

```
// *** Telegram dependencies ***
compile 'org.json:org.json:chargebee-1.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.6'
compile 'org.telegram:telegrambots:2.4.4.5'
```

-- Update:
I'm getting also these warnings:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

Comment: The stack trace suggests you are running this from the IDE. Have you tried re-importing your Gradle file in IntelliJ?

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich yes, I did it. Still not seeing it.

Comment: have you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024908/apache-httpclient-android-gradle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed in this way. On dependencies I have added this:

```
// *** Telegram dependencies ***
compile 'org.json:org.json:chargebee-1.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')    
compile "org.telegram:telegrambots:3.3"
```

and inside android section I have added this:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    compile.exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}
```

Now, I'm able to execute TelegramBot code without runtime exception.